# MYSQL circular Replication: lost data on Master

Tags: mysql, replication

**EDITED: Some description of the full procedure was missing.**

We have two MYSQL servers, A and B. 
Some units are saving on A, some others on B.

Till a few days ago all new lines saved on B were copied every 5 minutes on A, without a proper replication (just a normal copy: due to the little amount of data involved this was a quick & dirt solution).

**Then we set a Master-Master replication** in order to have a proper backup: now A replicates its own lines on B, B replicates its own on A.

B's database has been removed and a new one created with mysqldump from A.

That's working and we see currently new lines replicating from A to B and from B to A.

Today we found out something strange.
**A single table in A misses some 1.700.000 rows out of 10 millions. The data of this table have been originally saved on A.**

Strange enough **these lines have been replicated on B.**
All other tables are OK apart another couple that miss some 20.000 lines only.

The only hypothesis we have is that

1. A saved the lines on B
2. for some reason A thought that B has a "fresher" version of these lines
3. A removed the original lines waiting for a replication that never came.

Is this possible? Or what could have happened? 
Any link to online info would be great.

Comment: Is it a Master Slave Replication or Master Master?

Comment: Are this lines created on B or A?

Comment: @A.Blub, I described better the issue and what happened. I hope that now it is clear. 
The lines are missing from the ORIGINAL table, while they are present in the REPLICATED one. That is very strange...

Comment: Sounds realy strange. Here how the replication system works: The master generate a binlog (history) of his actions and this will be executed on the slave replication absolutly blind until a query fails. There is no function that checks which line is newer or search a missing line. So A have to executed a REMOVE, but B would never send this query from his binlog and A would write it in his binlog and would send it to B. So i have no idea how this could normaly be. The replication system had to be off and resetted after the REMOVE queries

Comment: That's very strange indeed: there are reason for them to disappear on the SLAVE, not on the MASTER. And they disappeared AFTER the replication, otherwise there wouldn't be on the SLAVE.

We try to wait a little bit to see if the lines "reappear". I read that this could happen if the DB understands that there was an error and it is trying to recover the data... 

Thank you for your explanation.